# SWIFT: cannon insert value to NSTextView From ViewController

Tags: swift

I created file ViewController.swift

Here is the content of it

```
import Cocoa

public class ViewController: NSObject {

    @IBOutlet var textView: NSTextView!

    func InsertText(string:String) {        
           textView.insertText(string)
    }  
}
```

Then I bind textView to my NSTextView in my xib

and

now I want to insert text from AppDelegate via Controller

I do

```
let controller = ViewController()   
controller.InsertText("Hello")
```

and it throw an error

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

which means that textView in nil, but why it is nil and how do I insert text using another class. if I do the same just in AppDelegate it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `let controller = ViewController()` ctrl-drag the view into your AppDelegate, name it reasonable and use that.

Comment: Where do you instantiate ViewController? I guess you're a bit mixed up. Normally you create a ViewController for a NSTextView as such and bind it in the XIB. Then you can use that from the AppDelegate.